# Making a message system

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have created a messaging system with MySQL structure is as follows

```
      `message_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `message_from` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `message_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `message_body` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `message_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `message_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `message_read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`message_id`),
      KEY `message_from` (`message_from`),
      KEY `message_to` (`message_to`)
```

Currently The PK is an AUTO_INCREMENT so I am wondering if using this kind of key will be efficient for this type of system. Also the main reason why i am having a asking this question is to help in my function I have been having some issues with loading more messages. due to the fact that messages are deleted the PKs will not be consistent such as `1,2,3,10,255,300`. When I try to run the more function using

```
(SELECT MAX(message_id)
 FROM member_messages 
 WHERE (message_to = :userId
 AND message_from = :friendId)
 OR  
 (message_to = :friendId
 AND message_from = :userId))AS max_id,
FROM member_messages AS MSG
WHERE (MSG.message_to = :userId
AND MSG.message_from = :friendId)
OR 
(MSG.message_to = :friendId
AND MSG.message_from = :userId)
AND MSG.message_deleted = '0'
HAVING MSG.message_id >= max_id - 20
AND MSG.message_id <= :upperId 
ORDER BY message_id ASC
```

In effect this query should return messages from the last 20 entered, but due to the PK being inconsistent sometimes no messages are returned. Eg. if the max_id is 200, 200- 20 is 180 and the messages with ID between this range are deleted or not associated with this members(userId) recipient(friendId). Any insight into this problem as to whether I should change the key type or change the query itself? Thanks for your time.

## EDIT

Just a side note I used ASC because I wanted the newest messages to appear at the bottom of the DIV, while the fetched results would be older and appear at the top.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is: You're querying for data and *you are aware* that the data that fits your constraints might have been deleted by the time you run the query. So: Change your query or don't delete your data. Also: comparing `message_time` to `:upperId` looks wrong because it suggests comparing a date to an ID (probably numeric?), but maybe this does make sense in your system...

Comment: That was a mistake, i corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary key is fine. I don't see a reason to change it.

The issue you are having is because you are basing your query on the `messsage_id` and it being without gaps. You could base your queries on the `message_time` column (I suppose this holds the datetime that the message was sent).

Even if you keep using the `messsage_id` for the queries (assuming that biggest id means the latest message - which may not always be correct), you can still write a query that returns always 20 messages, gaps or not - just change `ORDER BY message_time DESC` to `ORDER BY messsage_id DESC` in the 3 places it appears:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (   ( SELECT message_id, message_time,
               'U <- F' AS direction
               message_read, message_body
        FROM member_messages AS msg
        WHERE message_to = :userId
          AND message_from = :friendId
     --   AND message_deleted = 0
        ORDER BY message_time DESC
            LIMIT 20 
      )
    UNION ALL
      ( SELECT message_id, message_time,
               'U -> F' AS direction
               message_read, message_body
        FROM member_messages AS msg
        WHERE message_to = :friendId
          AND message_from = :userId
          AND message_deleted = 0
        ORDER BY message_time DESC
            LIMIT 20 
      )
    ORDER BY message_time DESC
        LIMIT 20 
  ) AS tmp 
ORDER BY message_time ASC;
```

Other issues:

You probably meant to have the `deleted = 0` check on both cases (message sent by me to friend and sent by friend to me). If yes, undelete the commented line above - and note that `AND` has higher precedence than `OR` in SQL. The condition you probably wanted to use was (note the removed pair of parenthesis):

```
WHERE (    MSG.message_to = :userId
       AND MSG.message_from = :friendId
      OR 
           MSG.message_to = :friendId
       AND MSG.message_from = :userId
      )
  AND ...
```

So, you could write the query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM member_messages AS msg
WHERE (    MSG.message_to = :userId
       AND MSG.message_from = :friendId
      OR 
           MSG.message_to = :friendId
       AND MSG.message_from = :userId
      )
      AND message_deleted = 0
ORDER BY message_time DESC
    LIMIT 20 ;
```

I used `UNION` for efficiency reasons. Complicated conditions with `OR` may not be optimized very well. You could also add an index on `(deleted, message_from, message_to, message_time)`.

Comment: I will try some tinkering in a bit, but I think you understand my concept, getting all the messages in one view sent from me to you and from you to me. If `UNION` will be more efficient then I think that is the route I need to take also I was curious about using an index on `deleted` and `message_time`, how would i be using that index? Just a side note I used ASC because I wanted the newest messages to appear at the bottom of the DIV, while the fetched results would be older and appear at the top.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you asking about the index. The above 4-column index would be more than enough - for this particular query - and probably the best. Of course, adding an index for every query you have, will have you soon with too many indexes - and that is not usually good (for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE efficiency). Efficient indexing requires you evaluate all the queries/statements you need running and making some balance between excessive and no indexing.

Comment: What is the purpose of 'U <- F' AS direction in your first query sample?

Comment: 'incoming' (`User <- Friend`) or 'outgoing' (`User -> Friend`) message.

Comment: One more question, because I want to understand the concept and get what I was doing wrong. How will I get messages in batches of 20, at first I want to get the newest 20 messages then the 20 messages before that and so on etc..